# Using a common variable between two services on the same server

Tags: rust, rust-tonic

I am trying to see if this is the right tool for my use case and playing with some hello worlds.

I currently have two proto definitions:

- `helloworld.proto`, implementing the service `Greeter` (with associated messages, the same as in the hellowworld example)
- `wonderfulworld.proto`, implementing the service `Wonderful` (with associated messages, very similar, but does not take any argument in the request and returns something else).

I followed the Hello World example of Tonic, and created my service with

```
 Server::builder()
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(greeter))
        .add_service(WonderfulServer::new(wonderful))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;
```

Now the thing is that I would like to have a common variable, let's say `world_name`, for both services Greeter and Wonderful to use and modify.
Could I do this, and what would be the recommended way to proceed?

I have tried:

1. Implementing both `Wonderful` and `Greeter` on the same `MyGreeter` struct, but then I can't chain the `add_service` as I did here, since the `new()` constructor uses value and not borrow, and I don't know how else to do.
2. Creating a `MyServer` struct with a `world_name` variable, and look on the API/online if I could somehow use this struct as the server to add services, but I didn't find anything at all.
3. Using some form of global singleton... I guess it works but meh... not a big fan if it's possible to do otherwise

Following is my full `server.rs` file in case it's useful.

```
use tonic::{transport::Server, Request, Response, Status};

use hello_wonderful_world::greeter_server::{Greeter, GreeterServer};
use hello_wonderful_world::{HelloReply, HelloRequest};

use hello_wonderful_world::wonderful_server::{Wonderful, WonderfulServer};
use hello_wonderful_world::{WonderfulRequest, WonderfulReply};

pub mod hello_wonderful_world {
    tonic::include_proto!("helloworld"); 
    tonic::include_proto!("wonderfulworld");
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyGreeter {}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyWonderfulWorld{}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Greeter for MyGreeter {
    async fn say_hello(
        &self,
        request: Request<HelloRequest>, // Accept request of type HelloRequest
    ) -> Result<Response<HelloReply>, Status> { // Return an instance of type HelloReply
        println!("Got a request: {:?}", request);

        let reply = hello_wonderful_world::HelloReply {
            message: format!("Hello {}!", request.into_inner().name).into(), // We must use .into_inner() as the fields of gRPC requests and responses are private
        };

        Ok(Response::new(reply)) // Send back our formatted greeting
    }
}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Wonderful for MyWonderfulWorld {
    async fn its_a_wonderful_world(
        &self,
        request: Request<WonderfulRequest>)
        -> Result<Response<WonderfulReply>, Status> {
        let reply = hello_wonderful_world::WonderfulReply {
            message: format!("And I said to {}: What a Wonderful World", request.into_inner().name),
        };

        Ok(Response::new(reply))

    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "[::1]:50051".parse()?;
    let greeter = MyGreeter::default();
    let my_wonderful = MyWonderfulWorld::default();

    Server::builder()
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(greeter))
        .add_service(WonderfulServer::new(my_wonderful))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: What you are looking for is probably `Shared State`. If you would like to share some data between services (actually threads) you have to keep data behind `std::sync::Arc` and `std::sync::Mutex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```rust
pub struct SharedState {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyGreeter {
    shared_state: std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<SharedState>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyWonderfulWorld {
    shared_state: std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<SharedState>>,
}

use tonic::{transport::Server, Request, Response, Status};

use hello_wonderful_world::greeter_server::{Greeter, GreeterServer};
use hello_wonderful_world::{HelloReply, HelloRequest};

use hello_wonderful_world::wonderful_server::{Wonderful, WonderfulServer};
use hello_wonderful_world::{WonderfulRequest, WonderfulReply};

pub mod hello_wonderful_world {
    tonic::include_proto!("helloworld");
    tonic::include_proto!("wonderfulworld");
}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Greeter for MyGreeter {
    async fn say_hello(
        &self,
        request: Request<HelloRequest>, // Accept request of type HelloRequest
    ) -> Result<Response<HelloReply>, Status> { // Return an instance of type HelloReply
        println!("Got a request: {:?}", request);

        // here get the shared state and lock it
        if let Ok(shared_state) = self.shared_state.lock()
        {
            println!("Got the lock");
            println!("Name: {}", shared_state.name);
            println!("Age: {}", shared_state.age);
        }

        let reply = hello_wonderful_world::HelloReply {
            message: format!("Hello {}!", request.into_inner().name).into(), // We must use .into_inner() as the fields of gRPC requests and responses are private
        };

        Ok(Response::new(reply)) // Send back our formatted greeting
    }
}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Wonderful for MyWonderfulWorld {
    async fn its_a_wonderful_world(
        &self,
        request: Request<WonderfulRequest>)
        -> Result<Response<WonderfulReply>, Status> {

        // here get the shared state and lock it
        if let Ok(shared_state) = self.shared_state.lock()
        {
            println!("Got the lock");
            println!("Name: {}", shared_state.name);
            println!("Age: {}", shared_state.age);
        }

        let reply = hello_wonderful_world::WonderfulReply {
            message: format!("And I said to {}: What a Wonderful World", request.into_inner().name),
        };

        Ok(Response::new(reply))
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "[::1]:50051".parse()?;
    
    let shared_state = std::sync::Arc::new(std::sync::Mutex::new(SharedState {
        name: "John".to_string(),
        age: 32,
    }));
    
    let greeter = MyGreeter {
        shared_state: shared_state.clone(),
    };
    
    let my_wonderful = MyWonderfulWorld {
        shared_state: shared_state.clone(),
    };

    Server::builder()
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(greeter))
        .add_service(WonderfulServer::new(my_wonderful))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

I used `std::sync::Mutex` but you maybe can use `std::sync::RwLock`.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I need! Perfect, thanks a lot!